# Prove that there exists (a,b,c) belonging to a set such that $abc \subseteq xyz$ for all $(x,y,z) \in E$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

This question was asked in a previous year paper for a masters exam for which I am preparing and unfortunately I have no clue on which result should I use to solve it.

> Let E={ $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x,y,z >0 , xy+yz+zx =1$}. Prove that there exists (a,b,c) $\in E$ such that $abc \geq xyz$ for all (x,y,z)$\in E$.

so, I have to prove that there exists  a maxima a,b,c belonging to E.

I tried using the method of lagrange multipliers but I was unable to prove it. I think there must be some other methods.

So,can you please help.

I have studied real analysis from  Tom M Apostol and Complex analysis from Ponnusamy and silvermann

Comment: It sounds like Lagrange multipliers; maximize $xyz$ subject to $xy+yz+zx=1$.  However, since both the objective function and the constraint involve symmetric polynomials there may be an easier way.  I'd guess $a=b=c=\frac1{\sqrt3}$

Comment: Straightforward application of AM/GM inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an application of the arithmetic mean/geometric mean inequality.

The arithmetic mean of $xy$, $yz$, and $zx$ is $\frac{1}{3}$.

The geometric mean of the three will be $\sqrt[3]{x^2 y^2 z^2} = (x y z)^{2/3}$.

So we know that $(xyz)^{2/3} \leq \frac{1}{3}$, hence $xyz \leq \frac{1}{3^{3/2}}$.

And equality is achieved when $x = y = z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.